# Native await/async and webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm developing an extension for chrome 55+, and using webpack 2 to make pack everything. The problem is that I started using async and await.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR in content_script.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: keyword (function) [./content_script.js:1,0]
[content_script.js:1630,6]
```

For a simple file like this:

```
async function test() {

}
```

I don't want to use babel to convert it into non native async code, due to only targeting chrome 55+ any way, but I can't seem to find a way to configure UglifyJs to accept this, or use a different version which supports this.

My webpack config:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "content_script": [
            "./content_script.js"
        ],
        "browser_action": [
            "./browser_action.js"
        ],
        "background": [
            "./background.js"
        ],
        "options": [
            "./options.js"
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: "manifest.json" }
        ]),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "browser_action_popup.html"),
            inject: true,
            chunks: ["browser_action"],
            hash: false,
            filename: "browser_action_popup.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "options.html"),
            inject: true,
            chunks: ["options"],
            hash: false,
            filename: "options.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UglifyJs does not understand ES2015+ syntax yet. As an alternative you can use [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili) which works with every syntax understood by babel.

There is a [babili-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/babili-webpack-plugin) that can be used like`webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` in your webpack config.

```
const BabiliPlugin = require('babili-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...

  plugins: [
      new BabiliPlugin(options)
  ]
};
```

For the list of available options see [babel-preset-babili options](https://github.com/babel/babili/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-babili#options).

You can also use the [babili CLI](https://github.com/babel/babili#cli) if you don't want to include a webpack plugin.

Comment: I still get the UglifyJS error after adding this. It seems that webpack automaticly runs Uglify without even adding the plugin. I can't find an option to stop it from doing that.

Comment: It does not. I only included the CLI part because I thought you run it outside of webpack, because you didn't specify the plugin in the posted config. Make sure you're using the correct config.

Comment: Scrap that, I added -p which is a shorthand for --optimize-minimize and other options (I run webpack through a package.json command). Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out how Uglify was being run even though I didn't ask for it. The answer is -p (or --production) does it automatically.